# How to append the result from a nested loop

Tags: google-colaboratory

I´m trying to append the nested loop in a single frame:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.set_option("display.max_colwidth", 150)
#pd.options.display.format = '{:.2f}'.format

def busca_informes_cvm(ano,mes):
   url = 'http://dados.cvm.gov.br/dados/FI/DOC/INF_DIARIO/DADOS/inf_diario_fi_{:4d}{:02d}.csv'.format(ano,mes)
   return pd.read_csv(url, sep=';')

list_anos = [2020, 2021]
list_meses = [6,7]

for i in list_anos:
  for j in list_meses:
    saida = busca_informes_cvm(i,j)
saida
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could append data frames using the `append` method starting from an empty data frame.

```
saida = pd.DataFrame()
for i in list_anos:
  for j in list_meses:
    saida = saida.append(busca_informes_cvm(i,j))

saida
```

It's likely to be inefficient for large datasets.